# New, unexpected operand error with @ operator with ndarray or matrix operands

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been able to use `@` to do matrix multiplication before, but for some reason, it is not working anymore. I'm running Python 3.5.4, and in either IPython 6.2.1 or notebook 5.0.0, this unexpected error comes up:

```
In [1]: from numpy import arange

In [2]: A = arange(5)

In [3]: B = arange(15).reshape((5,3))

In [4]: A @ B
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-455d622f3b50> in <module>()
----> 1 A @ B

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Using the `matrix` type doesn't help:

```
In [5]: from numpy import matrix

In [6]: A = matrix(arange(5))

In [7]: B = matrix(arange(15).reshape((5,3)))

In [8]: A @ B
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-455d622f3b50> in <module>()
----> 1 A @ B

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'matrix' and 'matrix'
```

I'm at a total loss here. Is the `@` operator deprecated? Am I missing something obvious? This came up while I was revising a notebook that worked fine about a year ago. Is there some other information that would help diagnose whatever is going on?

Comment: Does [`numpy.matmul(A,B)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.htm) succeed?  Or `eye(3) @ eye(3)`?  I don't know the answer off-hand, but either of those might help narrow it down.  Also, what version of `numpy`?  You need [at least v1.10](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) (search for `@`)

Comment: I think the numpy version may be it. I have been updating packages since I posted this question, and the error has gone away.

Comment: Should I delete the question? It seems like maybe I should...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!  I don't have a good sense of the deletion rules, but I know there are too many posts on Meta about it :) .  My personal opinion?  Add an answer noting that you updated packages (and listing which pertinent ones, if at all possible), then accept it once the system will let you.  It will then be a well-asked question with a clear answer, and might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it turns out to have been an issue with having the right version of numpy, per cxw's comment. I have updated numpy, and everything seems to be working fine now.